# Calculating the gravitational acceleration inside of a planet

Tags: gravity, homework-and-exercises, mass, acceleration

Plant X has a radius of 5000 km and is composed of two layers.

The first inner layer ranges from the centre to 2000 km from centre, it's density is 8 kg / dm^3.

The second layer ranges from 2000 km to 5000 km from the centre, it's density is 4 kg/ dm^3.

What is the gravitational acceleration inside the planet at 4000 km from it's centre?

Comment: Don't you basically just ignore everything outside of 4000 km? And for the rest, just assume all the mass is concentrated at the center?

Answer (score 2):

The key point to solve this problem is you should know the material on a spherical shell has no gravitational effect inside the shell. So to calcite the gravitational acceleration, you just need to consider the contribution from mass inside the $4000km$ sphere.

I think you should already know how to calculate the gravitational acceleration of a planet has constant density:

$Gravitation Force = Gm\frac{\iiint\rho(r‘)dV}{r^2}$

where $r$ is the distance of object $m$ from the center of planet, and $\rho(r')$ is the density of planet, it's a function of $r'$ (as in your problem). We know the gravitation force on the object $m$ is $Force = ma$, so the acceleration is

$a = G\frac{\iiint\rho(r‘)dV}{r^2} = G\frac{4\pi\int\rho(r')r'^2dr'}{r^2}$

In your case, $r = 4000km$, using the conclusion stated in my first paragraph, and the density stated in your problem, we should have this:

$\iiint \rho(r')dV = 4\pi\int\rho(r')r'^2dr' = 4\pi(\int_0^{2000km}\rho_1r'^2dr' + \int_{2000km}^{4000km}\rho_2r'^2dr')$

where $\rho_1 = 8kg/L$ and $\rho_2 = 4kg/L$ as stated in your problem.

Also, there is a simple way to do this problem. Since the density here $\rho_1$ is twice of $\rho_2$, so you can think like this: the gravitational force of this single planet can be effectively equal to a total effect of two planets have same densities, but one planet only has $2000km$ radius, and the other has $4000km$ radius, so calculate the acceleration of both planets at the radius of $4000km$, and then combine these two to get the total acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to do the problem for a planet of constant density? You really need to do this problem before you try the layered planet.

EDIT: Matt has answered that he knows how to "calculate" g for the constant density case, but this answer troubles me because I wasn't thinking of a calculation when I asked if he knew how to "do" the problem. I'm going to tell him how I "do" the problem and hope it will help him to "calculate" the answer. For the planet Earth, the gravitational force *inside* the planet (that is, if you drilled a tunnel to the center of the earth) is linear with depth. In other words, when you get halfway to the center, g is 4.9 m/sec^2. I know this for all kinds of reasons but you should be able to convince yourself it is true before you go any further.

When you are *above* the surface, the force is 1/r^2. So for example when you are 4000 miles above the surface, g is 2.45 m/sec^2.

These are the two cases you need to know, and as Qmechanic has correctly suggested, the problem as given should be solved as the superposition of these two cases.

Comment: I know how to calculate g for something with constant density but not this problem.

Comment: @Matt: Hint #2: Can one think of the problem as a superposition of constant-density-problems, which you already know?